# Can't find where Chrome extension is running from

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to modify a Chrome extension, and want to use the debugger to step through a rare bug. However, I'm having trouble determining where the code is actually being executed from. I understand that it's not where I installed it from. (Or if it is, setting a breakpoint there doesn't work for some reason.) My Google searches indicate that it ought to be in:

```
%localappdata%/Google/Chrome/User Data/[my profile]/Extensions
```

with the extension ID. I looked in `chrome://extensions` and it has ID: `mdhiioiejhhdaicgjpgaoojeeblblmok`.

I found the Extensions folder, and it has a number of extensions, but none with this ID, and none that have the extension's javascript files. I searched local app data for the ID and did find a folder, but it's in "Sync Extension Settings" and doesn't contain any code.

Where else could it be? I'm in Developer mode and installed it as an unpacked extension, and it definitely installed and can run.

Comment: If you installed it as an unpacked extension it is in whatever folder you installed it from, it doesnt get moved to chrome data directory

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is right, in his comment; if you loaded an unpacked extension in dev mode, it just stays where you loaded it from, and you can edit it there.

Also, (in case you forgot where you loaded it from) when you click the Details button for the extension:

[image]

and scroll down, you'll also be able to see the full path where it's loaded from:

[image]

Comment: Editing it from there definitely works, but setting breakpoints does not. I figured I could go to the Chrome debugger (cntrl-shift-i), add the folder under Sources/File System, and set breakpoints from there. But I never hit the breakpoints, even though the code is clearly executing because it's doing things I set breakpoints at. Which is why I concluded it's actually executing from somewhere else. I did eventually manage to get into the code by clicking on an exception in the console. It says the source is chrome-extension://mdhiioiejhhdaicgjpgaoojeeblblmok/src/inject/search.js

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my extension (packed) by typing out `chrome://version` on the address bar & looking at the **Profile path**

Will be something like this:

[image]